# Python code sharing and repositories?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I do scientific computing and am currently using MATLAB. I have however recently started learning Python. I find the MATLAB Central file exchange very helpful and people share a lot of their programs there.

Are there equivalent code repositories and places where people share the programs they have written for the Python community? Especially for engineering and scientific computing.

Answer (score 1):

Since programming in Python revolves around using modules and packages, you might find Python's package index [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) very useful. It allows you to easily integrate other people's code into your programs.

If you're more interested in finding out how some thing were implemented, then you might want to explore code on [github](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=python&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories). There is a ton of code out there, so you should be able to profit from it.

In case you're interested in figuring out how to use some library for scientific computing, you can find detailed examples for [numpy](http://wiki.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List), [scipy](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook), [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/) and so on.

This might serve you as a good starting point for exploring Python code and examples.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.python

Answer (score 0):

The scipy Cookbook has small pieces of code, but they should only receive general-purpose and good-quality code:

http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook

Or the python package index:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi